# Vary scale of geom_point size by facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm using ggplot with facet_wrap to generate 3 side-by-side plots with linear models. In addition, I have another dimension (let's call it "z") I'd like to visualize by varying the size of the points on the plots.

Currently, the plots I generate keep the size of the points on the same scale across all 3 facets. I would instead like to scale the point sizes by facet - that way, one can quickly tell which point contains the highest "z" value for each facet.

Is there any way to do this without creating 3 separate plots? I've included a sample of my data and the code I used below:

```
x <- c(0.03,1.32,2.61,3.90,5.20,6.48,7.77,0.75,2.04,3.33,4.62,5.91,7.20,8.49,0.41,1.70,3.00,4.28,5.57,6.86,8.15)
y <- c(650,526,382,110,72,209,60,559,296,76,48,64,20,22,50,102,176,21,20,25,5)
z <- c(391174,244856,836435,46282,40351,27118,17411,26232,59162,9737,1917,20575,1484,450,12071,13689,133326,1662,711,728,412)
facet <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C")
df <- data.frame(x,y,z,facet)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=z)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  facet_wrap(~facet)
```

Comment: did any of the answers work?, please indicate which one

Comment: sorry for the delay - all 3 of the answers involved rescaling my z values within each facet, appending the new values to my data frame, and then using the geom_point(aes(size)) argument with my new z. they were all successful in resolving my issue.

the differences between the answers existed in the method of scaling. in the end, i chose the answer which suggested i scale my z-values using their within-facet z-scores. i thought this was the most statistically elegant answer.

thank you all for your help! also this is my 1st question on stackoverflow, so my upvotes aren't showing up yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would just take the mean of the `df$z` by each `df$facet`

```
AverageFacet  <- df %>% group_by(facet) %>% summarize(meanwithinfacet= mean(z, na.rm=TRUE))
df <- merge(df, AverageFacet) 
df$pointsize<- df$z - df$meanwithinfacet
```

Now each point size depends on the mean of the facets

```
> head(df,10)
   facet    x   y      z meanwithinfacet   pointsize
1      A 0.03 650 391174       229089.57  162084.429
2      A 1.32 526 244856       229089.57   15766.429
3      A 2.61 382 836435       229089.57  607345.429
4      A 3.90 110  46282       229089.57 -182807.571
5      A 5.20  72  40351       229089.57 -188738.571
6      A 6.48 209  27118       229089.57 -201971.571
7      A 7.77  60  17411       229089.57 -211678.571
8      B 0.75 559  26232        17079.57    9152.429
9      B 2.04 296  59162        17079.57   42082.429
```

and plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
        geom_point(aes(size=pointsize)) + 
        geom_smooth(method="lm") +
        facet_wrap(~facet)
```

[image]

Looks like this, not sure about the legend though.

You could also instead of using the absolute difference from the mean use the how many standard deviates from the mean a given `z` is

```
AverageFacet  <- df %>% group_by(facet) %>% summarize(meanwithinfacet= mean(z, na.rm=TRUE), sdwithinfacet= sd(z, na.rm=TRUE))
df <- merge(df, AverageFacet) 
df$absoluteDiff<- df$z - df$meanwithinfacet
df$SDfromMean <- df$absoluteDiff / df$sdwithinfacet


ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
        geom_point(aes(size=SDfromMean)) + 
        geom_smooth(method="lm") +
        facet_wrap(~facet)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The method below reassigns z to it's z-score **within** it's facet:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot)
require(magrittr)
require(scales)

x <- c(0.03,1.32,2.61,3.90,5.20,6.48,7.77,0.75,2.04,3.33,4.62,5.91,7.20,8.49,0.41,1.70,3.00,4.28,5.57,6.86,8.15)
y <- c(650,526,382,110,72,209,60,559,296,76,48,64,20,22,50,102,176,21,20,25,5)
z <- c(391174,244856,836435,46282,40351,27118,17411,26232,59162,9737,1917,20575,1484,450,12071,13689,133326,1662,711,728,412)
facet <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","C","C")

df <- data.frame(x,y,z,facet)
df %<>% 
    group_by(facet) %>% 
    mutate(z = scale(z)) # calculate point size within group

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, group = facet)) + 
    geom_point(aes(size=z)) + 
    geom_smooth(method="lm") +
    facet_wrap(~facet )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to rescale size for each facet to take values in (0,1]:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(facet) %>% 
  mutate(newz = z/max(z)) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=newz)) + 
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  facet_wrap(~facet)
```

[image]